# How can I get the "lowest closest" index in a sequence in Python?

Tags: python, list, indexing

This might be a simple math problem for many, but it has proven to be a bit confusing for my humble mind.

Given a list l:

```
l = [0,20,40,80,100]
```

And a random int between the first and the last elements:

```
r = randrange(l[0], l[-1])
```

How can I get the "lowest closest" index?. Let us suppose that the random resulting int is 39. In this case, I want to get the index of number 1 (The second), considering that the int 39 is between the range of 20 and 40.

Here's the code I'm using to philosophize about it:

```
from random import randrange
l = [0,20,40,80,100]
for e in l:
    r = randrange(l[0], l[-1])
    print str(e-r) + " | " + str((e, r))
```

Comment: Is `l` always sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list is sorted use Python's [`bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html):

```
>>> import bisect
>>> a = [0, 20, 40, 80, 100]
>>> n = 39
>>> bisect.bisect_left(a, n)
2
```

Note that `bisect_left` gives you the index of an insertion point needed to maintain sorted order.  In your case that's element after the one you are looking for.  You could simply subtract 1 from the result, but you then run the risk of getting an incorrect result of `-1`.  A simple helper function fixes this and throws an `ValueError` when there is no valid result.

```
>>> def find_lt_index(a, x):
...     i = bisect.bisect_left(a, x)
...     if i:
...         return i-1
...     raise ValueError
...
>>> find_lt_index(a, n)
1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked perfectly. I was implementing a "snap_to_grid" method, and the available positions were within a list. So, I needed just that, and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
def closest(l, r):
    for i in l:
        if i >= r:
            return l.index(i)-1
    return None
```